# How to customize boxes?

Tags: boxes

I want make block in my document like javadoc method description (see figure)[image: Here are what I want get]

I have wrotten a macro:

```
\def\makemybox{%
\noindent%
\fcolorbox[HTML]{9EADC0}[HTML]{F9F9F9}{%
    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \vbox{%
            \noindent%
            \fcolorbox[HTML]{9EADC0}[HTML]{DEE3E9}{%
                \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\textbf{Method name}}       
            }\par%
            \noindent%
            \makebox[\textwidth][l]{Method description}     
        }
    }
}}
```

but I get wrong boxes. See figure[image: This is what I get]

How I can fix my macro? I tried to set \fboxsep but I had no result.

Comment: You might want to try the `tcolorbox` package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

Answer (score 5):

With `tcolorbox` it's easy.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{DEE3E9}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{F9F9F9}
\definecolor{blue3}{HTML}{9EADC0}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
      top=0pt,
      bottom=0pt,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt,
      boxrule=0.4pt,
      breakable,
      colback=blue2,
      colframe=blue3,
      colbacktitle=blue1,
      coltitle=black,
      fonttitle=\bfseries,
      title=#1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Method name}
asdfgfgbaaf
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{DEE3E9}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{F9F9F9}
\definecolor{blue3}{HTML}{9EADC0}

\mdfdefinestyle{mybox}%
{leftmargin=0pt, rightmargin=2pt,innerleftmargin=5pt,
frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulecolor=blue3,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue1,
%frametitlerulewidth=0.4pt,
%linewidth=0.5pt,
backgroundcolor=blue2,
linecolor=blue3,
frametitlefont={\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}},
}

\newmdenv[style=mybox]{mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[frametitle={Method name}]
asdfgfgbaaf
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]